# A perfect (honest) pangram that is understandable for a regular native user?

Tags: phrase-requests, alphabet

Pangrams were pure wordplays, that because of IT has become a nice tool to test keyboard and fonts, assuming they are easy to remember and short. Therefore perfect pangrams are so nice: you don't need to repeat any character (with the exception of the space).

I've looked on the [list of pangrams](http://clagnut.com/blog/2380/) and I've noticed that most of them are either not perfect or are heavily using acronyms, initials, own names etc. (which I call not "honest", because it's a bit cheating).

Those "honest" looked like a gibberish for me:

> Jink cwm, zag veldt, fob qursh pyx

However, those are real English words, only I doubt a bit, a regular native speaker would understand them. So 2 questions arise:

1) Are such pangrams as above understandable for a regular English native speaker?

2) If not, are there any others that would be perfect, honest (no acronyms, exotic own names etc.) and written with commonly known words?

Just to give some context, the Polish perfect pangram

> Mężny bądź, chroń pułk twój i sześć flag.

would be understood by any native speaker, and it makes perfectly sense (be brave, protect your regiment and six flags). It's a poetry masterpiece, you can say.

Comment: English doesn't have accented characters, so one might accuse the Polish one of "cheating". Allowing accented characters increases the possibilities greatly.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Polish doesn't have accented characters too. A perfect pangram is a pangram, which uses **each** character of the alphabet exactly once, and this is exactly the case there. In fact, I've always thought it increases the difficutly because there are more characters to use, and some are very rare. But in fact, it may be the case with any character in any alphabet, even the shorter one.

Comment: So Polish counts the characters `ąężź` as different from `aez` and presumably they have their own place in the alphabet. Didn't know that. (I did know that ł and l are different, though, although I would still call that an accented character.)

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. The alphabet doesn't have enough vowels to avoid using any of them twice while keeping to well-known vocabulary. I had to look up "cwm," which appears to be a borrow from Welsh. But if it were fully Anglicized, we'd probably have changed the spelling by now.

Comment: @frances yes, it could be exactly the case. The consonant clusters arey very typical for Polish, which makes using all consonants and not running out of vowels much easier. It seems, that the challenge isn't fair for all participants :)

Comment: This is probably the shortest one that would make sense to a casual reader: "Waltz job vexed quick frog nymphs." (28 letters)

Comment: Isn't this primarily opinion based? Just asking.

Comment: With no further context, I only understood _cwm_, _veldt_, and _fob_ of the ‘perfect’ pangram you cite. The rest is nonsense to me.

Comment: If Polish 'honest pangrams' include ł,ó,ś etc, shouldn't English ones include æ and œ ?

Comment: In english, æ and œ ligatures aren't letters, although they are letters in some Scandinavian languages. In the past they were used in Latin and Greek words to mark an etymological connection, but in modern English they are rarely used. According to wikipedia the three letters you mentioned are part of the Polish alphabet.

Comment: @ghoppe, not that it’s really relevant, but just for the record: _æ_ is a letter in Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic, and Faeroese; _œ_ is only a letter of the alphabet in French (that I know of, at least).

Comment: The classic, of course, is "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back."  There is also one, at one time commonly used to display type faces, that begins "How does one assess and evaluate a type face?", but I don't know the rest of it.

Comment: @frances The spelling of "cwm" is different in English and the meanings are slightly more specific as well. In English it's spelt [coomb](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/coomb)

Comment: 1) No, most of the pangrams at that site are completely opaque when heard (and barely understandable even with study when read) 2) Most of those are as short as possible. Longer ones can be quite simple to understand, like the classic "A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Comment: To reinforce @Mitch above on the question of "Are such pangrams as above understandable for a regular English native speaker?" The answer is no, absolutely not-- none of them are. Very literate readers are certainly able to pick out some of the individual words (as discussed above), but these sentences *all* scan as gibberish-- this appears to be no more than an academic exercise for English.

Answer (score 8):

A Google search turned up a number of candidates.

With 28 letters, there are a few which can be made:

> Waltz job vexed quick frog nymphs (courtesy of Ronan)
>   Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow
>   Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox
>   Waltz, nymph, for quick jigs vex Bud

There's at least one 27-letter pangram, which makes sense but is probably better thought of as a headline:

> Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymph

And if you allow standard abbreviations, you **can** do 26:

> Mr Jock, TV Quiz PhD, bags few lynx

I vote ***Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow*** as the best (28 characters; repeats *a* and *o*).

---

Update: The perfect pangram ***Quartz glyph job vex'd cwm finks*** — another headline — appears in a number of internet pages, too, along with O.A. Booty's explanation, "Despicable vandals from the valley are thwarted by finding a block of quartz with carvings already on it." But I don't know if the Welsh word *cwm* is understandable to a regular native user.

As Frances has commented, English has only five vowels (and *y*). Any word with *q* automatically uses *u* and another vowel, unless Arabic words (*suq*) or Chinese words (*Qi*) are allowed.  In the last example, using the Welsh word *cwm* introduces another vowel which makes more words possible.

Comment: _Cwm_ is perfectly understandable for me (though of course more likely to be spelt _coomb(e)_), but then I'm not sure if I'm really a ‘regular’ user…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, me neither. It's similar to the reason why (in my line of work) developers should never write user guides.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I would think *cwm* is a Welsh valley, *co(o)mbe* is a West Country valley and neither a Welshman nor a West Countryman would thank you for confusing the two.

Comment: @Tim, I’m sure you’re right. According to the dictionary, a _cwm_ isn’t even a valley, but a cirque—but since I have no idea what the difference is, and most likely wouldn’t be able to tell one from the other if I were standing in it, that doesn’t help me much. I would assume a cwm to be in Wales, but apart from the fact that there don’t seem to be (m)any co(o)mb(e)s outside the British Isles in general, I wouldn’t assume such a one to be in any particular geographic location.

Comment: *"Mr Jock, TV Quiz PhD, bags few lynx"* is certainly vastly preferable to *"Jink cwm, zag veldt, fob qursh pyx"* - it makes sense as a sentence, and all the words would be recognizable to most people.   Perhaps the latter makes sense as a sentence too, I can't say as I only recognise a few of the words.

Comment: ‘Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow’ is 29 letters. (A, O and U are repeated.)

Answer (score 3):

Steve Galen, on [his blog](http://stevengalen.blogspot.ca/2011/03/perfect-perfect-pangram.html) suggest the following perfect pangram:

> **GQ's oft-lucky whiz Dr. J, ex-NBA MVP**

What makes it so interesting is that it describes a real situation.

- Dr. J. is the nickname of professional basketball player [Julius Erving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Erving), who is retired from the [NBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Basketball_Association) (ex-NBA)
- Erving has won the [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Basketball_Association) award 4 times
- He appeared on the cover of [GQ](http://www.gq.com/) magazine in February, 2011:

[image: GQ cover]

Answer (score 2):

My favorite Perfect Pangram (26 letter ) is "**Fox TV Janglers whiz by muck PDQ**".  I can't remember where I heard it, though. As a lover of hairless cats, one of my favorite "nearly perfect" pamgrams is "**Jackdaws love my big Sphynx of quartz**".

Answer (score 2):

While it's not short, characterwise, this is the only five-word pangram I know of, making it snappy and easy to remember: “**Amazingly few discotheques provide jukeboxes**”

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the grammar presented in the most popular 26 character perfect pangram:

> Mr Jock, TV Quiz PhD, bags few lynx

So I used the same style of using a name to give the sentence structure and found the following headline style phrase to be the most pleasing to me:

> J. W. Covek finds quartz BMX glyph

...still a silly sentence though.

Answer (score 0):

The classic pangram is:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

(I'm honestly rather surprised that this hadn't been posted as an answer yet.)

It's easy to understand, easy to remember and it just has a ring to it.

Comment: No one has posted that pangram yet because it's not an answer to the OP's question, which is about _perfect_ pangrams, i.e. pangrams that don't repeat any letters.